# C# export to excel, file download is fine when test on local, but corrupt on server

Tags: c#, excel

I'm working my project using Orchard, this is my code for exporting datas to excel

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(string type)
    {
        var lst = _donHangService.GetAll(type);
        var html = _ajaxHelper.RenderView(this, "InDanhSachDonHang", lst);
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Danh-sach-don-hang.xls");
        this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        byte[] temp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html.ToString());
        return File(temp, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    }
```

I run a test on LocalHost, it worked fine, I can download the excel file and can open it.

Then I deploys my project to server, and try to download excel file from my site, but when I open the file, only ms-excel application appear, and nothing show, even no error pop up.

I try to open it by notepad, I can see my data, it's still here.

Comment: The file is probably "blocked" in Windows because it came from the internet.  View the properties of the file in File Explorer and select "Unblock" and see if it works.

Comment: ah, so it's the problem, I can open it now, thanks. Hmm, but it's still weird, because 2 month ago I didn't meet this issue, I can download and open normally, and I also didn't modify anything in this Export method. It's always work fine until now.

Comment: I believe this is a recent change in the OS and noticed this with Excel in the last month or so.  You have to add your URL to the trusted sites for it not block files.  Interesting though is this only affects Excel files.  Word files are downloaded and opened fine.